# How do you perform boolean operations over all elements of an array and mix the result together?

Tags: ruby

I want to `AND` or `OR` all the elements in an array, but with some control, as shown via the hash element selection. Here is the behavior that I wish to achieve:

```
a = [{:a => true}­, {:a => false­}]
a.and_map{ |hash_element| hash_element[:a] }
#=> false
a.or_map{ |hash_element| hash_element[:a] }
#=> true
```

Is there a slick, clean way to do this in Ruby?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `all?` and `any?` for that:

```
a = [{:a => true}, {:a => false }]
a.any? { |hash_element| hash_element[:a] }
#=> true
a.all? { |hash_element| hash_element[:a] }
#=> false
```

Answer (score 3):

```
a = [{:a => true}­, {:a => false­}]
a.all?{ |elem| elem[:a] }
a.any?{ |elem| elem[:a] }
```